# Объясните, что означают записи в командной строке

Tags: cmd, npm

По делам жизненным нужно мне удалить несколько модулей из npm. Эти модули - browser-sync и gulp. Ввёл в командной строке `npm uninstall -g browser-sync` и `npm uninstall -g gulp`; вроде как что-то выполнилось и окно командной строки забилось чем-то непонятным для меня. Прошу объяснить, что это означает.

P.S.: Если вопрос глупый прошу быть адекватными людьми и явно указать на это.

P.P.S.: На скрине результат работы команды `npm uninstall -g gulp`

[image: Результат работы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто зависимости снеслись вместе с пакетами, что удалили, и их список отображен

Comment: Спасибо большое, устал уже голову ломать, что это значит)